# Java: Add a Class Property Dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, properties

I'm relatively new to Java and have dug through the reflection capabilities, but for some reason can't figure out the following:

I need to get the String name of an instantiate class. Seems that I cannot find a way to do this with reflection, so I thought to add a class property dynamically that would contain the name of the class as a String.

How would I go about that?

Alternatively, I thought of creating a Public String property in the class that I assign the name of the instantiated class in the constructor. Didn't really figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Why not just use `instance.getClass().getName()`?

Comment: Thanks, Jorn. Thought of that, but that returns the name of the class and not that instantiated name. I'm sure I'm confusing the terminology.

Class: org.myapp.MyClass
Instance: MyClass myNewClass = new MyClass():

What I need is the String for myNewClass.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Oh I see, well that information is not always available (java 8 has a special compiler option for it though.). It is not available through the reference itself, but rather through the declaring class or method.

Comment: Needing to iterate through a bunch of HTML page input fields using Selenide/Selenium. I'm reading a list of fields from a configuration file and create form field classes using the field names in the config file. Each field has its own class therefore. I need to get to the field name later for setting purposes without statically specifying the name of the field. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So, Jorn, that would actually be preferred. When declaring the class, how would I set the name property without typing the name of the class?

Comment: I think your best option is probably a `Map<Name, Object>` which you fill while reading the configuration file.

Comment: It seems I had misremembered, the extra info was only available for parameter names. But I think Marvin's last suggestion is a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the name of a class as commented by Jorn Vernee you can use `instance.getClass().getName()`

Since you mention dynamically creating a string, I guess you may mean that you want the name of the object itself. The simplest way to get the object name is to construct the object and pass a name to the constructor to initialise a member string.

Something like

```
public class Enemy
{
    private String name;

    public Enemy(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

Enemy orc = new Enemy("orc"); // could be an array of references instead of a var
orc.getName(); // returns the name of the object, obviously the name is whatever you construct the object with; so you could use any object identifier you like (such as a hash), this also means you can just construct the object and store its reference in an array
```

Comment: Thanks, George. Jorn's suggestion gives me the name of the class, absolutely. What I am hoping to get though is the name of the object. Your solution works, although I then have to pass the name of the object I am creating, an extra step I was hoping to avoid. :-)

This may sound silly, but to get the name of an instantiated object I'm surprised that there is not a more straight forward way in Java. I thought that reflection perhaps would be the answer, but I haven't seen any property getter or method to do so. Again, I'm new to the language, so forgive the newbie approach to how Java works.